# Pass dictionary to view and use it in HTML/Razor fully

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, razor

This is model:

```
namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class myExampleModel
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        public Dictionary<int, string> returnDict ()
        {

            dict.Add(0,"a");
            dict.Add(1,"b");
            return dict;
        }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class myExampleController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult meth2()
        {

            myExampleModel myExampleMod = new myExampleModel();

            ViewData["dict"] = myExampleMod.returnDict().Count;
            return View(ViewData);
        }
    }
}
```

and view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>meth2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <span>@ViewData["dict"]</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works, and I see in html `2`.

But I need pass whole `Dictionary` from controller to view, so, when I try in controller:

`ViewData["dict"] = myExampleMod.returnDict();
 return View(ViewData);`

and In HTML/Razor I try counting of  `Dictionary` elements:

`<span>@ViewData["dict"].Count</span>`

I get error:

`'object' does not contain a definition for 'Count'...`

Question: what I am missed here?

Comment: Why aren't you using a strongly-typed model in your view?

Comment: @ Moo -- @model WebApplication4.Models.myExampleModel  -- I add this code  in view file. is this right syntax in this case?

Comment: You are missing a cast to `Dictionary<int, string>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ViewData` is of `Object`. Try casting this to `Dictionary` before accessing it's property

```
<span>@((ViewData["dict"] as Dictionary<int, string>).Count)</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to cast `ViewData["dict"]` to `Dictionary<int, string>`

Normally I create a variable in the page top section.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var Dictionary = (Dictionary<int, string>)ViewData["dict"];
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>meth2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <span>@Dictionary.Count</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

try using Strongly-Typed Model (STM)

Controller:

```
public class myExampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult YourAction()
    {
        return View(new YourModelExample());
    }
}
```

in View:

```
@model Dictionary<int, string>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>meth2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <span>@Model.Count</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```